# Index Beyonds Bound Errror while Adding Row to Static Cell in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a static cell UITableViewController that has contained some static rows. The controller itself contains 3 section. I intended to add a row every time the user add a new object resulted from other controller via modal segue. I implemented all these using storyboard and by wiring it up to the Custom UITableViewController i've made.

Firstly, i have a tableView controller on storyboard. Then i create a custom class of UITableViewController that overrides these below methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (section == 2) {
        return [appDelegate.userIds count];
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        UITableViewCell *cell;
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"userIdCell"];
        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"userIdCell"];
        }
        appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [appDelegate.userIds count]]);
        NSLog([[appDelegate.userIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] userId]);
        cell.textLabel.text = [[appDelegate.userIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] userId];
        return cell;
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        UITableViewCell *cell;
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addCell"];
        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"addCell"];
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Add User ID";
        }
        return cell;
    } else {
            return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Note that appDelegate.userIds is a mutable array that i instantiated from an AppDelegate class and appDelegate is an instance of it.

Via modal segue to other input form viewController, i add a User object to appDelegate.userIds array.

This is the segue preparation

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tambahUser"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        TambahUserViewController *TambahUserViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        TambahUserViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

and this is the method i implemented from the ControllerDelegate

```
#pragma mark - tambahUserViewControllerDelegate

    - (void)tambahUserViewController:(TambahUserViewController *)controller didAddUser:(User *)user
{
    [appDelegate.userIds addObject:user];
    NSInteger lastRowIndex = [appDelegate.userIds count] - 1;
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:2];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)tambahUserViewControllerDidCancel:(TambahUserViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Initially the 3rd section (section 2) has no rows, so i added first row into it. There was no problem after i added first user. An error shown up after i added second row. It said,

```
> 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Can you please show me what's wrong with my code. Thank you.